# Rewrite Part of URL .htaccess or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I want to rewrite part of url:

I need this:

```
http://example.com/subdir/form.php?email=sampleemail%40gmail%2com&name%20(awf_first)=John&name%20(awf_last)=Richardson
```

To be rewritten to:

```
http://example.com/subdir/form.php?email=sampleemail%40gmail%2com&first_name=John&last_name=Richardson
```

So basically:
- name%20(awf_first) rewrites into first_name
- name%20(awf_last) rewrites into last_name

I tried with .htaccess RewriteRule but it didn't work out:

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on

#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^&first_name=$ &name%20(awf_first)= [L]

#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^&last_name=$ &name%20(awf_last)= [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match against the query string for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)name%20\(awf_first\)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1first_name%2 [L,R,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)name%20\(awf_last\)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1last_name%2 [L,R,NE]
```